# how to run msbuild script through cruise control

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am getting execption when i am running cruise control by iis or cctray and below is ccnet.config.i wanted to run my scrip through cruise control .please let me know how to relove this issue

```
<project name="Visteon">
         <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/</webURL>

        <triggers>
            <intervalTrigger seconds="110" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
        </triggers>

        <tasks>
            <msbuild>
                <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
        </executable>
                <workingDirectory>E:\workingfolder_123</workingDirectory>        
                                <buildArgs>E:\CCnet.xml /p:Configuration=release</buildArgs>
                <timeout>1800</timeout>
                <!--  30 minutes -->
                <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\
            ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
            </msbuild>
        </tasks>
    </project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

**my scripts is like this**

```
<Target Name="GetSource">
    <Message Text="Checking out trunk into $(SourceDirectory)" />
    <SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="$(SvnCheckoutPath)"
        LocalPath="$(CheckOutPath)"
        UserName="aa"
        Password="aa">
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </SvnCheckout>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="GetSource;Clean;" />
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <!-- Clean, then rebuild entire solution -->
    <MSBuild Projects="$(CheckOutPath)\SUPPLIER_SOFTWARE.sln" Targets="Clean;Rebuild" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Please post the complete exception and the CCNet debug log file of that project. Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CruiseControl Template below

```
<project name="MyCodeFolder Project" queue="MyQueue" queuePriority="1">    
<tasks>
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>D:\Projects\MyCodeFolder</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>CCnet.xml</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /nologo /p:Configuration=Release</buildArgs>
    <targets>
    </targets>
    <timeout>4800</timeout>
  </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

As for the build script you will need the root to have Project node and set default target name main as the entry point. Please see below:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Main">
     <Target Name="Main">
            //Do Something
     </Target> 
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing project file tag e.g.

```
<projectFile>your_msbuild_script-here</projectFile>
```

http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/MsBuild%20Task.html

I'm also not sure what exactly `E:\CCnet.xml` is. If this is your msbuild file, put it
inside `<projectFile/>` and try again.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for reply..yes E:\CCnet.xml is my msbuild scripts file.please let me know how to run my targests which are defined in above scripts.

Comment: add one more parameter in the list of parameters e.g. /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build  /t or /target tells msbuild which is going to be your target to execute